# Import of more than one App from Samsung App Store

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, profile-page

I tried to add some Apps to my Careers 2.0 profile.

I managed to add one App from the Samsung (bada) App Store. But when I try to add another one this always overwrites the first one.

Comment: Are you still running into this problem? The second project should only override the first if it has the same url.

Comment: This is working now. Thanks!

Comment: Kein Problem. :)